# How can I disable Alt-Scroll zoom in XFCE4 (Xubuntu)

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, xfce, zooming

In XFCE4 desktop environments, <kbd>alt</kbd>+scroll wheel zooms my entire desktop. I'm finding this very annoying because sometimes I flick the scroll wheel to go to the top of a document then press the <kbd>alt</kbd> key for a some unrelated keyboard shortcut and find myself zoomed in so far I can't see anything at all.

Is there any way to disable this feature?

Comment: To get out of the zoomed desktop, just hold `ALT` and use your mouse wheel to scroll in the opposite direction

Answer (score 92, accepted):

There is an easy way, without losing the moving windows feature.

1. Open **Settings Editor**
2. Go to Channel *xfwm4*
3. Disable Property *zoom_desktop*

Comment: This is the only acceptable answer. Unfortunately, the property doesn't seem available yet in Xfce 4.10.

Comment: Just to be clear, since I didnt notice, 'settings editor' != 'settings'.  you have to choose 'settings editor' inside 'settings', and then this magic works :-)

Comment: Every time I setup a new Laptop with XFCE I come back here :)

Comment: Thank you! That `zoom_desktop` thing is such a PIA!

Comment: If you still want to be able to use desktop zooming, check out [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1286478/21005).

Comment: @BastianVoigt, what is a PIA?

Answer (score 15):

Here is how disable this feature from the command line:

```
xfconf-query --set false --channel xfwm4 --property /general/zoom_desktop
```

If you get this message:

```
Property "/general/zoom_desktop" does not exist on channel "xfwm4".
If a new property should be created, use the --create option.
```

then run this command instead:

```
xfconf-query --create --type bool --set false --channel xfwm4 --property /general/zoom_desktop
```

Comment: as GUI seem to change a lot this is the answer that works in 2020

Answer (score 14):

To activate or deactivate, there is also another option in Window Manager Tweaks.  Under Compositor, the option to enable or disable display compositing will also enable or disable desktop zoom.

Comment: Thanks! Because Compositor was disabled, I was unable to find/utilize this feature.

Answer (score 4):

To disable this setting from the gui now in xfce4, do the following:

1. Click your Application launcher icon (typically the top-left corner of the screen) & select "Run Program..."
   Alternatively, use the keyboard shortcut "Win-R"
2. In the "Application Finder" window that appears, type:
   xfwm4-tweaks-settings and click "Launch"
3. Click "Compositor" tab
4. Untick 'Zoom desktop with mouse wheel'
5. Click "Close"

Answer (score 0):

Translation:

Opens the System Setup window, then enter the administrator settings window and section accessibility this box that enables or disables this function.

---

Abre la ventana de configuración del sistema, luego entra al gestor de ajustes de ventana y en la sección accesibilidad esta la casilla que habilita o deshabilita esta función.
[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like what tctimmeh was asking at all, and you're posting several years later than the correct solution. Did you mean to post that here? To be clear, the magnifier is an "accessibility" option, but zooming in on the entire desktop is not. I'm on a new installation of Xubuntu, and accessibility has never been enabled and would require restarting the computer, but alt+scroll desktop zooming has been there from the beginning.

Comment: That doesn't answer this question, but helped me to solve another probem.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to be able to use desktop zooming, I have a couple of tricks by which you may be able to prevent accidental desktop zooming.

You can control which key is bind to desktop zooming at *Window Manager Tweaks > Accessibility > Key used to grab and move windows*. You can even select "none" so that it effectively disables desktop zooming, but that will disable the mentioned window grabbing function, too. Someone has requested ability to configure a distinct key for the zooming feature [here](https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfwm4/-/issues/276).

I made a utility that you can run in background. It blocks subsequent scrolling events (and other events of the given pointer device), while you press a modifier key after starting scrolling in X11. That is especially useful, if you device has inertial scrolling function that you can not or do not want to disable. See [my answer for another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/612499/111181) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In manjaro I did this on the settings editor

Here you have to uncheck zoom_desktop value:

[image]