# Xubuntu - shortcut for magnifying screen

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, xfce

I started using Xubuntu a few weeks ago, and I'm annoyed with a strange behaviour : when I accidentally type a certain keyboard shortcut (yet to be determined), my screen shifts to a "magnified" mode (it gets a 10% zoom and starts to move the opposite way of my mouse pointer).

I'd like to know the shortcut (so I can at least leave this mode without disconnecting my session everytime...) and if possible, how to disable this completely. I found nothing related in the Keyboard manager.

Comment: this is piece of shit!!! who did it?

Answer (score 16):

Found the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/479465/how-to-disable-alt-scroll-zoom-in-xubuntu-14-04)
The default shortcut is Alt + mouse wheel and it can be disabled in Window Manager Tweaks