# How to exit from magnified screen that moves with the mouse on Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, display-resolution

I have accidentally pressed some key combination that enabled a feature that I cannot turn off and cannot name.

The visible desktop area I see on monitor is enlarged and as I move the cursor, the visible area moves with it. I do not see the whole desktop, only a part of it.

How can I turn this off, whatever it is? Inside accessibility, the screen reader is turned off, it is something else.

Comment: Press the `Super` aka `Meta` key and the `minus` sign (located below the row of function keys) together. You can activate/deactivate the `zoom` feature in `Desktop Effects`.

Comment: @DKBose Holy sheet that is kind of cool. I see myself using this feature

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Kubuntu has a section called *Desktop Effects*. You can access it from *System Settings* under *Desktop Behavior*.

In the first section of *Desktop Effects*, you'll find *Zoom*. If you activate it, you'll be able to zoom your desktop.

[image: Zoom]

Settings for the zoom feature can be accessed by clicking on the circled icon in the image above.

[image: Zoom settings]

The default keyboard shortcut for zooming in is <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> pressed simultaneously. For zooming out, the default is <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> pressed simultaneously. *`Meta` is the `Super` or `Windows` key*.

Answer (score 20):

Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and use mouse scroll wheel down.

On a laptop touchpad you can hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and swipe two fingers down on the touchpad.

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: For years, I've accidentally done this, I never knew what triggered it and how to undo it. It is called "zoom desktop" and happens when you hold down the alt key and use mouse scroll wheel up. If you never want it to happen again, see https://askubuntu.com/a/671147/47769.

Comment: On a laptop touchpad, moving two fingers up or down simulates mouse scroll.
In my case, I was holding Alt, and inadvertently touched the pad with two fingers sliding upward.  Holding Alt and sliding two fingers down undid the effect.

Answer (score 6):

Key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> got me back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this issue this morning. Thanks to my toddler :D !!.

None of above solution worked for me, I was using Ubuntu 18.04.6.

I found below link helpful.
URL: `https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/07/how-to-enable-screen-magnifier-in-ubuntu-18-04-19-04/`

I am repeating steps given on the link in case the link longer works for some one.

1. Open `Dconf Editor` and then navigate to `org/gnome/desktop/a11y/applications`
2. There turn on the toggle for “screen-magnifier-enabled”.

That's it.

Cheers!